# Replace iSight camera on MacBook Air late 2010 (A1369)

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, camera, webcam

My MacBook got a small water damage some time ago. Luckily everything still works without any problems except the iSight camera, which is no longer detected. I reinstalled Mac OS X a couple of times since, so I'm sure it's not a software issue. Since [a replacement looks pretty cheap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HFI0UK0) and I have all the tools to open up my MacBook, I was wondering, if there are any guides on how to replace the camera. I googled a lot and also checked on Youtube, but could not find anything suitable. How hard would such a replacement be? Can I make sure it's the camera and not some other hardware issue before I try to replace it? On the other hand how much would it cost to have the camera replaced by Apple?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is that in order to get to the iSight camera, you have to detach the display assembly from the body and then get the casing off, which probably means removing the display gasket and the display itself (non-trivial) because the iSight cable is routed behind the display.

You can find guides at [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Late+2010+Display+Assembly+Replacement/4512) on how to detach the display assembly (seems to be harder with an Air, it was simpler for my MBP), which appears to involve taking *everything* out of the bottom casing. And *then* you need to take apart the display. They don't even have a guide for this, you must look elsewhere (Youtube or so, but this should give you the idea that it's difficult).

**Long story short:** The replacement part may be cheap, but the procedure isn't, and is probably best left to a professional, unless you know what you are doing.